# How could I have a protocol-based data model, considering mutation and relationships?

Tags: ios, persistence, data-modeling, swift-protocols

I'm doing a bit of learning and am wondering if there's a sort of best practices way to do persistence framework agnostic data modeling.

I'm fine with trivial stuff, like:

```
protocol Item {
    var identifier: String { get }
    var name: String { get set }
}
```

and

```
struct SomeItem: Item {
  let identifier: String = UUID().uuidString
  var name: String = "New Item"
}
```

and its Manager, something like:

```
protocol ItemManager {

    /// get some objects matching query criteria
    func objects(matching query: Query) -> [Item]

    /// get a specific object
    func object(withID identifier: String) -> Item?

    /// commit these to disk.
    func save(_ object: Item) throws

    /// deletes the objects from disk.
    func delete(_ objects: [Item])

    /// creates a new object but does not save it.
    func create() -> Item
}
```

But suppose we now wanted to tag Items with Categories.

What's the best way to manage / mutate these relationships?  On the model, or via a Manager method?

Ultimately, I want to build a data model as protocol-oriented, and be able to swap out the persistence type.  For example for testing or mocking, or simply if I'm using CoreData to start, but then want to move something like Realm.io and not have to re-write my app.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction, be that links and resources for my consideration.

I know this question is a bit vague, but I don't know how else to ask it.  If I'm fundamentally thinking about this wrong, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

we've started modelling of the "data in motion" i.e. data protocol using UML Modelling Notation.
Data protocols are better expressed using UML class diagram notations.

In UML class is treated as Entity, Class Attributes same as attributes in entity, Association similar to relationship in ER modelling.

Please read through UML Modelling notation, for more details.

hope this helps.

Comment: I guess you're a fan of UML.  I have a bit of knowledge in that, but ultimately it's just a tool, and my question was about how to structure a generic interface for managing a data model.  i.e. if you have a protocol with a to-many relationship (say var items: [Item] { get set }) then do I really want to mutate it, or should I have a manager that's used for mutation, etc.